# How to design html a tag so that copy both text and href using ctrl + c

Tags: html, angular

I have requirement to render some a links using angular. That part is done. Following piece of code render a showing text on UI.

```
<tr ng-repeat="link in controller.links">
<td><a href="{{link.href}}" target="_blank">{{link.label}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Following is UI representation.

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Now , I want whenever I select all hyperlinks and press ctrl + c of system then it should copy both label (Test 1) and link attached to it at one go.
Is it really possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the clipboard (import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';), then you can add any string you want.
For example:
this.clipboard.copy(this.value + this.url);

Comment: In that case, I need to program . don't we have any tag setting that force us to copy both